# Language detection with NGINX using cookies

Tags: angular, nginx

I'm struggling with my nginx configuration for a while now and I cannot find the right solution.

I have a cookie set like this

```
language=de
```

And have the following nginx.conf

```
...
http {
    ...
    map $http_cookie $lang {
        "~*language=([^;]+)" $1;
        default en;  # Set default language
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen  [::]:80;
        server_name  localhost;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index index.html;

        location / {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/$lang;

            try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
       }
    }
}
```

What this should do is that when the cookie is set to `language=de` and I call `http://localhost:8080/foo` it should serve the file `/usr/share/nginx/html/de/index.html` (its an Angular app)

Right now it doesn't do that and nginx gives an error:

```
*1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/de" is forbidden, ...
```

Any suggestion what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to change the alias directive to root in your location block. The alias directive specifies a different document root for a particular location, while the root directive sets the document root for the entire server or location. The difference is that the alias directive replaces the part of the URI that matches the location, while the root directive appends the URI to the path. For example, if you use alias /usr/share/nginx/html/de, then the request for /foo will be mapped to /usr/share/nginx/html/defoo, which does not exist. If you use root /usr/share/nginx/html/de, then the request for /foo will be mapped to /usr/share/nginx/html/de/foo, which is what you want. For example, you can use the following code:

```
location / {
root /usr/share/nginx/html/$lang;
try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
}
```

Another solution is to add a trailing slash to the alias directive and the URI in the try_files directive. This will ensure that the URI is treated as a directory and not a file. This will also prevent the error of directory index being forbidden, which occurs when nginx tries to list the contents of a directory without an index filehttps://geekflare.com/httponly-secure-cookie-nginx/. For example, you can use the following code:

```
location / {
alias /usr/share/nginx/html/$lang/;
try_files $uri/ $uri/index.html;
}
```